# When is the school time starting?

Tags: grammar

Usually we say "What is the school time?" to ask the start and end of the schooltime.

If the schooltime is start from 8am to 12pm and I want to know the starting time. How should I ask?

"When is the school time starting?"

"The school time starting from when?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best would be "What time does school start?"

Another option is "When does school start?", but that phrasing is less clear. It could be interpreted as asking about the date rather than the time.

Comment: Would it confuse with the mean school commence time(built)? @Michael Stroud

Comment: Yes. In adult parlance there is really no such noun collation as "school time", though it can be and is used when talking to children. At least that seems to be the position in Britain.